# Getting error in Facebook connect's all.js line 87

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I am trying to connect facebook in my website. It was working fine but then from last week onwards, I have started to face a problem with Connect to Facebook. As soon as the page is loaded, I get an error in the console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'createElement' of undefined (all.js:78)
>   r.register.init (all.js:78)
>   r.create (all.js:78)
>   ja.init (all.js:81)
>   m.provide.init (all.js:136)
>   window.setTimeout.window.fbAsyncInit.hasRun (all.js:137)
>   w (all.js:18)
>   (anonymous function) all.js:137

This error causes all the Connect to Facebook Button unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have overwritten `window.self` with something that no longer points to `window`. This can easily be tested in the console by doing `self === window` - this should be returning true but is most likely returning false.